# export from mysql database to excel file

Tags: php, excel, csv, export-to-csv, xlsx

I'm trying to export table from MySQL database to excel file using PHP it's working correctly but Arabic language words displays as strange letters I tried everyhting in the internet but nothing worked you can see my code and tell me what I can do pleeeeeeeeease I'm working on it for 3 days now :(
thanks a lot.

**Result:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5ZDl.png]

**Code:**
`

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'charity';
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$columnNames = array();
if (!empty($rows)) {
    $firstRow = $rows[0];
    foreach ($firstRow as $colName => $val) {
        $columnNames[] = $colName;
    }
}
$fileName = 'files.csv';
header('Content-Type: application/excel;charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
ob_end_clean();
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, array_values($columnNames), ';', ' ');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $outp = fputcsv($fp, array_values($row), ';', ' ');
}
fclose($fp);
flush();
exit;
```

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of the excel file? Also, does your php file use the correct encoding?

Comment: When you open your .csv file by excell indicate/choose `;` as delimiter.

Comment: everything is utf-8 (database encoding, excel encoding, php code encoding like you see in this code)

Comment: i need php code not excel way because it's working when i use data->from web-> and import the file and change encoding to utf-8 but my clien't not happy with this solution

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: you can use `mb_convert_encoding' php function to change of text encodind.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I use it in my code because when I use it I get an error!

Comment: @J.Litvak please if you can edit my code to add 'mb_convert_encoding' function and work correctly do it :)

Answer (score 0):

To change encoding use `mb_convert_encoding` function

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'charity';
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$columnNames = array();
if (!empty($rows)) {
    $firstRow = $rows[0];
    foreach ($firstRow as $colName => $val) {
        $columnNames[] = mb_convert_encoding($colName, "Windows-1251", "UTF-8");
    }
}
$fileName = 'files.csv';
header('Content-Type: application/excel;charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
ob_end_clean();
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, array_values($columnNames), ';', ' ');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
       $row[$i] = mb_convert_encoding($row[$i], "Windows-1251", "UTF-8");
    }
    $outp = fputcsv($fp, array_values($row), ';', ' ');
}
fclose($fp);
flush();
exit;
```

Comment: the file downloading to no end there is a problem with for loop

Comment: same problem infinity loop problem I'm sorry wasting your time but really I need help :(

Comment: the file never download it's keeping rise with no end

Comment: Can you Please help me.